# How to solve this problem with MapBox LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, map

I have a problem with my mapbox LWC. I am getting this error and don't understand what is the problem. Can someone give some suggestion?
[image]

My code:
**js**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import mapbox from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/MapBoxJs';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class Testing extends LightningElement {    
    connectedCallback() {
        Promise.all([
            loadStyle(this, mapbox + '/mapbox.css'),
            loadScript(this, mapbox + '/mapbox.js'),
        ]).then(() => {
            this.mapboxInitialized()
            ;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error loading D3',
                    message: error.message,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        });
    }
    mapboxInitialized(){
        L.mapbox.accessToken =
        "accesstoken";
        const map = L.mapbox
        .map("map")
        .setView([28.64686, -106.08543], 15)
        .addLayer(L.mapbox.styleLayer("mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11")); 
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<template>
   <div class="map" lwc:dom="manual"></div>
</template>
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>54.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
<targets>
  <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
  <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
  <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
</targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: please  edit your question to remove access token as it is sensitive information.  i have removed it  you can also accept my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.map` method expects an `id` or an element. You can't reliably predict the `id`, so you need to use the element instead:

```
.map(
  this.template.querySelector('.map')
)
```